# Method or Delegate or Func

Tags: c#, methods, lambda, delegates, func

I have read posts on this issue but could someone please dumb it down for me?
So I am currently exploring delegates and obviously there are uses such as events.
However for simple operations such as multiplying 2 numbers what is preferred?
Is it bad practice to overuse delegates?
Below is what I have been looking at.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication32
{
public delegate int Function2(int x, int y);

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {          
        Console.WriteLine("Method");
        Stopwatch sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Console.WriteLine("Method: " + Function(5, 5));
        sw2.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw2.Elapsed);

        Console.WriteLine("Delegate");
        Stopwatch sw4 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Function2 g = Function;
        Console.WriteLine("Delegate: " + g(5, 5));
        sw4.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw4.Elapsed);

        Console.WriteLine("Anonymous");
        Stopwatch sw3 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Function2 f = delegate(int a, int b) { return a * b; };
        Console.WriteLine("Anonymous: " + f(5, 5));
        sw3.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw3.Elapsed);

        Console.WriteLine("Lambda");
        Stopwatch sw5 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Function2 h = (x, y) => { return x * y; };
        Console.WriteLine("Lambda: " + h(5, 5));
        sw5.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw5.Elapsed);

        Console.WriteLine("Func Delegate");
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Func<int, int, int> function = (x, y) => x * y;
        Console.WriteLine("Func: " + function(5, 5));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
    }

    static int Function(int x, int y)
    {
        return x * y;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference.

```
delegate(int a, int b) { return a * b; };
```

and

```
(x, y) => { return x * y; };
```

will both be converted into the same anonymous class with anonymous methods. So from the efficiency point of view there is no difference. But lambdas are usually more readable and shorter so they are used in LINQ statements. There is nothing bad in wrapping you multiplying function in lambda just don't create too many of them (or for example don't create them in cycle) as it could lead to instantiating numerous of anonymous classes.